# The best way of preventing paragraphs from "pushing" other divs in a hover/float?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-float

I'm trying to make a 50%-50% (half-half) webpage that when the user hovers over one side, it expands and vice versa.

How do I prevent the words from the `<div #container>` ("This is the container") from moving and pushing down the `<div #panel1>` everytime I hover over it?  I'm trying to make the words go "under side" of panel1.  My code is below:

```css
#container {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  min-width: 100%;
  }

#panel1 {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  }

#panel2 {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px
  }

#container:hover #panel1 {width:30%; transition: 0.5s;}

#container:hover #panel1:hover {width: 70%; transition: 0.5s;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  This is the container (hover over me.). Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ac magna eget magna laoreet convallis ut et libero. "How do I prevent this paragraph from pushing down Panel 1 yet still be able to put words "under" the panel one?""....
  <div id="panel1">This is panel one.(hover over me.)
    <div id="panel2">This is panel two.</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: You want 50% panel1 and 50% panel2? and when panel1 or panel2 is hover it gets 100% width? correct me if im wrong.

Comment: I just want 50% panel1 and 100% container.  panel2 i don't care about since it's inside panel 1.

Comment: when hover to container what will happen? panel1 would get 30% width?

Comment: Yes.  it's just half-half.  When hover over container:  (container = 70%, panel1 = 30%)

Comment: Or maybe it's better to use 2 panels instead of container?

Comment: yah its much better. becoz your panel1 width is depending on the width of your container.